# Behaviour of classifying spaces of abelian groups under direct sums and tensor products

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, group-cohomology

Recall the notion of the [classifying space $|G|$ of a group $G$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space).

Is it possible to relate the classifying spaces $|A\oplus B|$ and $|A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B|$ of a tensor product or a direct sum of abelian groups $A$ and $B$ with the classifying spaces $|A|$ and $|B|$ of its factors?

In particular, how does [group cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology) (i.e. cohomology of classifying spaces of groups) behave under direct sums and tensor products?

Comment: The classifying space of $G \times H$ is homotopy equivalent (even homeomorphic, if you set things up right) to the product of the classifying spaces of $G$ and $H$.